# SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'arslan.akram123@gmail.com' for key 'users_email_unique

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

When i run a command php artisan db:seed it gives that duplicate  error in CMD 
here is my UserTableSeeder

```
public function run()
{
    $user = new App\User();

    $user->create([

        'name'=>'admin',
        'avatar'=>'avatar/image.png',
        'email'=>'arslan.akram123@gmail.com',
        'password'=>bcrypt('Nouman1122'),
        'admin'=>1,

    ]);

    $user->create([

        'name'=>'ali',
        'avatar'=>'avatar/image/png',
        'email'=>'ali_gujjar@hotmail.com',
        'password'=>bcrypt('password'),
        'admin'=>0,

    ]);
```

Comment: your `user` table have already one entry for column `email` with value  'arslan.akram123@gmail.com' which is unique, delete this record from table and then try

Comment: i try this but it doesnot work i do migrate:refresh before seeding but i can't understand why it giving me that error

Comment: delete this record from table

Comment: yea i did.. it doesn't work

Comment: i create database from strach but it gives me that error when i seeding data

Answer (score 0):

Oh I find the soultion

actually by mistake in my DatabaseSeeder i register Database seeder itself

$this->call(DatabaseSeeder::class);